# Best way to find a deprecation error with no location hint?

Tags: craft3, error-message, error

I'm getting a deprecation error about looping through element queries, but in my markup all my loops are being setup with the `.all()` method, so I'm struggling to find this.

And it's one that is coming up every time I clear my errors, so the CMS clearly still thinks it's an issue.

[image: Deprecation error]

Comment: Can you share what you see when you click on that "Stack Trace" link?

Comment: Opening few lines: https://imgur.com/a/fB6Jpu5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the list of file paths in the stack trace there will be one or more files in the `storage/runtime/compiled_templates` directory. In this particular case there is `storage/runtime/compiled_templates/1a/1a584296a...ccfb9.php` under number 33 in the stack trace. (If you're using PhpStorm you can press <kbd>shift</kbd> twice and paste in the filename to find it quickly.)

This file contains a PHP class that Twig [compiles](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/internals.html#the-compiler) when the template is first accessed, so that it doesn't need to parse through all the twig code converting it into PHP every time the template is accessed.

At the top of this file is a comment that contains the path of the actual twig template. If needed, you might be able to work out a bit more context by looking at code at the line number in the stack trace (it's the `:43` for this one). There will be another comment above this line that will tell you the line number in the twig template.

There may also be some clues in the stack trace itself. For example, here (again number 33 in the stack trace) you have the line:

```
twig_array_merge([], craft\elements\db\CategoryQuery)
```

This suggests to me that you're using the `|merge` filter, on a `craft.categories` query without calling `.all()` on it first, which also makes sense given the deprecation notice.

Comment: This is great! I was calling a category based on the category parameter in the URL but wasn't calling `.one()`.